# SoftLayer Hardware API : SoftLayer_Hardware::captureImage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using Fast Provision API, BM Servier provision is success. I want to capture image of BM Server.
Is there any payload(example) available for capture image for bare metal server.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/captureImage

I am unable to generate payload for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following REST request:

```
https://[username]:apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/[hardware_id]/captureImage
```

Method: POST

Json Payload:

```
{
      "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "myImageName",
            "description": "api test note"
          }
      ]
    }
```

**Where the supported OSes to create a flex image are:**

```
- Centos 5.x - 6.x
- Redhat Enterprise 5.x - 6.x
- Windows 2003 - SP2
- Windows 2008 RC2
- Bare metal platform installations NOT supported
```

**References:**

[create flex image](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/create-flex-image)

[what is flex image](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/what-flex-image)

Comment: The above payload is working for me. Thanks.                                          For BM Servers, normal image template creation supports apart from flex image creation ?

Comment: I'm afraid to say that only "flex images" can be created from a Bare Metal. But the Virtual Guest are able to create other kind of image (e.g. standard image: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/create-standard-image). It's good to know that it was helpful for you :), if you want up-vote it :). Thanks.

Comment: Yes i know we can create standard image for virtual server. In the similar way whether we can create standard image from BM Server ? Also once i create flex image from BM Server, i have option to provision virtual server and i can provision BM Server also. In this scenario what happens to the hardware model details.(CPU and Memory details)

Comment: can someone please answer this :After creating flex image from BM Server, i have option to provision virtual server and i can provision BM Server also. I provisioned Virtual Server, In this scenario what happens to the hardware model details.(CPU and Memory details) will it remains the same of BM Server ?

Comment: When a flex image is created, it takes into account the OS, size on disk, location. The hardware of server is not considered in this image. CPU and memory are not considered when creating the image.